# Where to put this method in OOP

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm programming a little system where authors can write posts and these posts should be displayed on the frontend.
So I have two main classes: Author, Post.

To show all posts of one author, I have created a method called "getPostIDs()" which returns an array of IDs from the posts this author has posted.

So far so good, but let's say I want to have a page where all authors are listed. Where should I put the method getAllAuthorIDs() ?

I researched this issue many times, not only concerning this example, but I really don't know what to look for exactly.

I'd be really thankful if someone could help me with this issue. I think this would really help me for other projects and cases.

Answer (score 4):

While @pguardiario has likely outlined the shortest way to do it, another way is to create a companion class next to the Author class that will receive methods that would have in common to return 0...n objects of class Author.

This makes sense from an OOP point of view because :

- That leaves the `Author` class implement only stuff related to the current `Author` object, each method only modifying $this. No static stuff there.
- Today you need all `Author` ids from the database, tomorrow you'll likely be needing alongside it more complex queries (all but some ids, some ids based on a set of criteria, etc), for example to populate some carefully curated `<select>` dropdowns across your site. The same might also apply to other entities in your model.
- In that class (which you may call for example **AuthorRepository**) you don't have to mark the method as static, allowing you the full OOP benefits to override/extend it as you like. That way you can also access some object hierarchy (e.g. service locator, database abstraction...) if it's relevant to your framework.

In any case and whatever your final choice will be, feel free to browse how existing ORMs (such as Doctrine, Propel) are addressing this problem for possible solutions.